# Group and aggrigate dates from List<MSProject.Task> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ms-project

I'm trying to group MS Project tasks, then get min and max dates for new object. I get a run time error "Object must be of type String" on the LINQ query. I'm fairly new to C# and even newer to LINQ.

Note: `GetTaskList(tasks)` takes the MSProject "Tasks" collection and returns a filtered `List<MSProject.Task>`

```
private List<WBSScheduleImport> GetWBSScheduleItems(MSProject.Tasks tasks)
{
    var taskList = GetTaskList(tasks);
    var wpList = new List<WBSScheduleImport>();
    var query = from t in taskList
        group t by t.Text21 into wp
        select new
        {
            WPID = wp.Key,
            BaselineStart = wp.Min(w => w.BaselineStart),
            BaselineComplete = wp.Max(w => w.BaselineFinish),
        };

    foreach (var result in query)//build a wbsscheduleimport item
    {
        var wp = new WBSScheduleImport();
        wp.WBSID = result.WPID;
        wp.BaselineStart = result.BaselineStart;
        wp.BaselineComplete = result.BaselineComplete;
        wpList.Add(wp);
    }

    return wpList; 
}
```

Updated: But now get an error saying "Object must be of type DateTime"

```
private List<WBSScheduleImport> GetWBSScheduleItems(MSProject.Tasks tasks)
        {
            var taskList = GetTaskList(tasks);
            var wpList = new List<WBSScheduleImport>();
            var query =
                from t in taskList
                group t by t.Text21 into wp
                select new
                {
                    WPID = wp.Key,
                    //BaselineStart = wp.Min(w => w.BaselineStart),
                    minDate = wp.OrderBy(w => w.BaselineStart).FirstOrDefault()
                    //BaselineComplete = wp.Max(w => w.BaselineFinish),
                };

            foreach (var result in query)//build a wbsscheduleimport item
            {
                var wp = new WBSScheduleImport();
                wp.WBSID = result.WPID;
                wp.BaselineStart = result.minDate.BaselineStart.ToShortDateString();
                //wp.BaselineComplete = result.BaselineComplete.ToShortDateString();
                wpList.Add(wp);

            }
            return wpList; 
        }
```

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: select new
                {
                    WPID = wp.Key,
                    BaselineStart = wp.Min(w => w.BaselineStart),
                    BaselineComplete = wp.Max(w => w.BaselineFinish),
                };

Comment: What is the type of `Text21`?  What about the types of the `BaselineStart` and `BaselineFinish` in `MSProject.Tasks` and `WBSScheduleImport`?

Comment: Test21 is string. The date fields are dynamic. Note: all date fields in MS Project Task class are dynamic... they can contain"NA" as well. All fields in WBSSchedule import are string.

Comment: The actual error is on line wp.BaselineStart = result.BaselineStart;
because it is a lazy query
try converting the dynamic date to string wp.BaselineStart = result.BaselineStart.ToString();

Comment: Same error:An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object must be of type String.